# How can i get count after 8 result in foreach loop in php?

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I want to show 8 result in single slide and other will be display in next slide. I have done this by following code

```
$counter = 0;
            foreach ($products as $product) {
if(++$counter % 8 === 0) {
                    $firstSlide = ($counter == 1) ? 'active' : '';
                    $slideItem = '<div class="item  ' . $firstSlide . ' "><div class="fill"></div>';
                    echo $slideItem;
                } 
}
```

Now i want to get count after 8 result. For example

```
result 1 
result 2 
result 3 
result 4 
result 5 
result 6 
result 7 
result 8

Slide 1 


result 9 
result 10 
result 11 
result 12 
result 13 
result 14 
result 15 
result 16

Slide 2
```

I have searched so far but couldn't find any solution, please guide me if anyone know how it will be possible.

Comment: have a look at http://php.net/array_chunk

Comment: It seems you forgot one `</div>` in $slideItem

Comment: @yolenoyer Yes I just forget here but I have added in my file

Comment: you mean you want to display Slide `1`, Slide `2`,..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use following code

```
$array      =   array(1,2,3,1,123,123,234,56,67,); // this is your actual array
$arrayChunk =   array_chunk($array, 8);
foreach($arrayChunk as $arrayNum=>$chunkArray) {
    if(is_array($chunkArray)) {
        foreach ($chunkArray as $value) {
            print $value.' ';
        }
    }
    print '<br> slide '.$arrayNum.'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code please.

```
$counter = 1;
foreach ($products as $product) {
    if($counter % 8 == 0) {
    $firstSlide = ($counter % 8 == 1) ? 'active' : '';
    $slideItem = '<div class="item  ' . $firstSlide . ' "><div class="fill"></div></div>';
    echo $slideItem;
    $counter++;
    } 
}
```